# Convert Changing string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one date in string  "18/07/2013 04:25:28 PM".How to convert this string to DateTime in c#.When I am trying to convert it into Date time I am getting an error
"Input String is not in correct Date format"

Comment: Was asked trilion times. Try `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`

Comment: Can you post the code you use to convert that string into a `DateTime`?

Comment: @Marcus - only in "weird" countries. ;P (dd/MM/yyyy vs. MM/dd/yyyy fight! *popcorn*)

Comment: no code and you can easly find a solution in SO to this without asking

Comment: @giammin, but thar requires effort, so..

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
        "4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM", 
        "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: He can parse with PM using `ParseExact`

Comment: I've changed the example. You must give the tt format with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("18/07/2013 04:25:28 PM");
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact("18/07/2013 04:25:28 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", culture);
```

Added another mechanism...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) using [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("18/07/2013 04:25:28 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following solution :

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("18/07/2013 04:25:28 PM", 
              "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To found the format string, I used [Custom Date and Time Format Strings in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)